# snprintf function keeps pausing and cause the program to terminate in C

Tags: c, struct, printf, malloc

I have been working on this function that takes a customer struct and returns an allocated string with detailed info using `snprintf` to form the string.

```
char* to_string(customer cus)
{
    char* buffer = (char*) malloc(BUFFER_SIZE);
    snprintf(buffer, BUFFER_SIZE, "||%-30s||%2d/%2d/%4d||%-30s||%-10s||%2d/%2d/%-4d||%-10.4lf||%-16s||"
    , cus.name, cus.birth.date, cus.birth.month, cus.birth.year, cus.address, cus.phone, 
    cus.opening.date, cus.opening.month, cus.opening.year, cus.opening, cus.balance, cus.cardnum);
    return buffer;
}
```

Detailed structs and macros:

```
#define FONE_SIZE 10
#define CARD_SIZE 16
#define NAME_SIZE 50
#define ADDRESS_SIZE 100
#define MAXCUS_SIZE 300
#define CHOICE_SIZE 18
#define BUFFER_SIZE 255

typedef struct {
    int date;
    int month;
    int year;
} date;

typedef struct {

    char name[NAME_SIZE];
    date birth;
    char address[ADDRESS_SIZE];
    char phone[FONE_SIZE];
    date opening;
    double balance;
    char cardnum[CARD_SIZE];
} customer;
```

I'm implementing the function like this:

```
void print_cus(customer* cus_arr, int cus_num)
{
    printf("||%-30s||%-10s||%-30s||%-10s||%-10s||%-10s||%-16s||\n", "Customer's name", "Birth day", "Customer's address", "Phone number", "Open date", "Balance", "Card number");

    for(int i = 0; i < cus_num; i++)
    {
        char* buffer = to_string(cus_arr[i]);
        puts(buffer);
        free(buffer);
    }
}
```

Then, when I run the program on Windows, it pauses and terminates. I used VS Code's debugger and noticed that the bug happened when the `snprintf` function was called. I completely don't know the reason for it and any help would be awesome. The debugger shows errors like this:

[image]

Comment: You don't check that the memory allocation succeeded.  You should.  You don't check whether the formatting had enough space.  I'd be your call on whether there is a risk there.

Comment: @Hibiki Supersanta, Please post how `cus` is assigned.

Comment: As long as you are consistent, the compiler won't mind you spelling `customer` as `custumer`, but people might spot the mitsake and wonder.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica The github project is here https://github.com/SFMSupersanta/premiumrepo/tree/main/Work/C/Ass

Comment: @JonathanLeffler yes, I should check it properly

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I will keep that in mind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You pass 12 data arguments to your `snprint` call but provide only 11 format specifiers.

It would seem to me that the `cus.opening` argument is superfluous – indeed, how does `snprint` know what to do with that *structure* argument?

Compiling your code as provided, clang-cl gives three warnings for that `snprintf` call:

> warning : format specifies type 'double' but the argument has type
> 'date' [-Wformat]
>  warning : format specifies type 'char *' but
> the argument has type 'double' [-Wformat]
>  warning : data argument
> not used by format string [-Wformat-extra-args]

Removing the `cus.opening` argument from the call removes all three warnings.

Also, as mentioned in the comments, you should always check that a call to `malloc` has succeeded and include error-handling code should it fail (i.e. returns `NULL`). And please read: [Do I cast the result of malloc?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/10871073)

Comment: Seems like the autocompletion of tab nine messed me up right there, I didn't notice a spare argument and thought everything was okay. Anyways this is an embarrassing moment in my life.

Comment: @HibikiSupersanta "I didn't notice a spare argument" --> Save time.  Enable all warnings and let a well enabled compiler detect such issues.